# delphi gridpanel last row height issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, tgridpanel

How to avoid gridpanel last row take higher than others?
I have 10 rows with 10 percent value

[image]

If I append a new row with 0 percent the prior row which tend to be the last row take the right height but a new row `borders` appears at the bottom which I don't desire

[image]

Comment: Is this by any chance connected to the space that could be used by the scrollbar at runtime? Did you try to disable scrollbars/hide them?

Comment: Use `Absolute` instead of `Percent` as `Size Type`. Design the outer bounds of the `TGridPanel` to be exactly number of rows times height of each row.

Comment: @Ancaron there is no such property scrollbar in TGridPanel...

Comment: @Tom Brunberg is that at run time...

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `SizeStyle=ssPercent` the size calculation includes a `double` value (the percentage). In `VCL` the result must be rounded to a whole number (= pixels). The code uses `Trunc()`, presumably to assure that the number of rows fit into the `GridPanel`. Then, the excess pixels (if any) are "given" to the last row.

Instead of `SizeStyle=ssPercent` you can use `SizeStyle=ssAbsolute` and define the row heights as number of pixels. In this case the calculation does not include float values and there's no need for rounding. In this case you can declare the height of each row e.g. 28 an if the height of `GridPanel1` is 280, then all rows are of equal height.

You can select `SizeStyle` in the IDE (Object Inspector) by selecting all `TRowItem` in the structure pane under `RowCollection`.

You can define these settings also at runtime.

---

*Edit after comment*

If you use `SizeStyle=ssPercent`, you need to make a choise between the two cases you show in your question.

If you use `SizeStyle=ssAbsolute`, you can use the `TGridPanel1.OnResize()` event to recalculate the item heights:

```
procedure TForm7.GridPanel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, toth, rowh: integer;
  gp: TGridPanel;
begin
  gp := Sender as TGridPanel;

  toth := gp.Height;
  rowh := toth div gp.RowCollection.Count;

  for i := 0 to gp.RowCollection.Count-1 do
    gp.RowCollection.Items[i].Value := rowh;
end;
```

In addition, if the color of the `GridPanel1` is the same as that of the form, you may want to set the `GridPanel1.BevelOuter=bvNone` which hides the border line of the `GridPanel1` and the empty space that appears beneath the rows (when `toth` is not evenly divisable) becomes unnoticeable.

Comment: thank's for the answer i need TGridPanel to be in percentage (Flexible) in my real project the gridpanel could be resized at run time absolute value can't help unless i recalculate them at rum time